# Gradient of $F (x, y) = \frac{x (x^{2} - y^{2} )}{x^{2} + y^{2}}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

LET

$$ F (x, y) = \frac{x (x^{2} - y^{2} )}{x^{2} + y^{2}} $$

$F(0,0) =  (0,0)$

I need to compute partial derivatives at point $(0, 0)$.

[image]

By doing regular method I found partials exist , but textbook stated they don't exist , which I do not seem to understand

Comment: Both partials exist. **Edit:** But it would probably be of much morehelp to you if you posted your work.

Comment: @GitGud ok thanks

Comment: @GitGud i did by definition .they existed but wheni look answer i got baffled and posted , but i will upload image of my work

Comment: @GitGud plase see my attempt

Comment: It's correct.${}$